# Migrate a php function from one case to another in the same file

Tags: php, fpdf

My developer left me out to dry and while im able to learn pretty quickly, actually adding code to excisiting piece of code is a struggle while reading the code makes sort of sense. My business got hit by corona and this piece of code is part of my core business. I have to solve this and sadly on my own account as im willing to pay if i had the recources.

I guess this is a very basic question for all but beginners but i'd love to understand it. Been spending alot of time just reading the code and now its time for help.

This piece of code

```
case 'Summary list':
    foreach ( $order_ids as $order_id ) {
        $user_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', true);
        $groups_user = new Groups_User( $user_id );
        $orders_group[$groups_user->groups[0]->group->name][$user_id][] = $order_id;
    }

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($orders_group as $group => $users) {

        // Group name
        $formater->custom_header($group);
        // Table header
        $formater->table_header();
```

Displays the group that the user is in on a PDF. Now i know that the foreach part defines the formatter part. the part in particulair is the

```
// Group name
$formater->custom_header($group);
```

Now in the same file i need to display that same group name in the following sequence

```
case 'Delivery note':
    foreach ( $order_ids as $order_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
        if(array_key_exists($order->get_user_id(), $orders_group)) {
            $orders_group[$user_id]['order_ids'][] = $order_id;
        } else {
            $orders_group[$user_id]['order'] = $order;
            $orders_group[$user_id]['order_ids'][] = $order_id;
        }
    }
    $og_count = count($orders_group);
    $og_i = 1;
    foreach ($orders_group as $user_id => $data) {

        // Delivery header
        $formater->delivery_header();
        // Client name
        $formater->custom_header($data['order']
                 ->get_formatted_shipping_full_name(), 5);
        // Client address
        $address = join( ", ", array_filter( array( 
                        $data['order']->get_shipping_address_1(), 
                        $data['order']->get_shipping_address_2(), 
                        $data['order']->get_shipping_city(), 
                        $data['order']->get_shipping_postcode() ) 
                        )
        );
        $formater->custom_header($address, 10);
        // Group name
        $formater->custom_header($group);
        // Table header
        $formater->table_header();
```

Now ive already put the

```
// Group name
$formater->custom_header($group);
```

part in there but i am unable to define it in the upper part.

Is someone willing to show me how i can get this to work and possibly explain it since i really like understanding it aswelll.

Edit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjn62.jpg

The "Registerd" part is what the

```
// Group name
        $formater->custom_header($group); prints.
```

In the 2nd image, the blue line, thats where i want that to appear aswell.

Comment: In the first part, `$group` exists, because the `foreach ($orders_group as $group => $users)` "creates" it, putting the current element's array _index_ into that variable. But with your second loop, you have different variable names there, `foreach ($orders_group as $user_id => $data)` - so if(!) this is supposed to follow the exact same logic, then it would have to be `$formater->custom_header($user_id);` in there.

Comment: ^^^ What he said, you keep beating me to the punch today CBroe

Comment: Adding $user_id gives "1" on output in de PDF wich in this case is the user_id inherited from wordpress. I really cant get it right by myself.